Best way to simply protect a next.js 14 API endpoint?
I have a website written in typescript, react, and next.js 14. I have a page where a player plays a game. If they get a high score, that score is posted to an api endpoint on my website (like "/api/games/highscore") and the high score is updated. However, I have nothing protecting this endpoint, so a malicious actor could technically just send a score of 1000 to that endpoint and ruin the fun. For a small-scale thing like this, what is the best way to protect my logic here so that a bad actor can not take advantage of this?

add cors and only allow certain origins?
